# Sequence several functions on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that stores several values from a HTML form, and that must work individually in order to store that info in any situation I need (ie before inserting on DB, or before udating info on DB...)

I need to be able to tell the system to execute this function (`'storeValues'`),and then execute any other (could be `'createNewClass'`, `'updateExistingClass'`... whatever).

How can I sequence this? I tried here to store values first and, WHEN DONE, execute another function aleting about a value, but it says "storeValues() is not defined", and it is defined:

```
$('.tableClassHeader').on('click', '.createClass', function(){
    storeValues().promise().done(function(){
        createNewClass();
    });
});

function storeValues(){
    cl_year = $('.newClassForm').find('select[name=cl_year]').val();
    cl_course = $('.newClassForm').find('select[name=cl_course]').val();
    }

function createNewClass(){
    alert(cl_year);}
```

I mean that storeValues function SHOULD BE a separate function with the possibility of being called from any other place, I know this problem could be solved by executing "createNewClass" from the "storeValues" function, but there will be times that I need to execute "updateClass" after "storeValues", not "createNewClass"

Comment: When you say "could be", do you base that on whether if the values are set or not?

Comment: By that I mean that it SHOULD BE a separate function with the possibility of being called from any other place, I know this problem could be solved by executing "createNewClass" from the "storeValues" function, but there will be times that I need to execute "updateClass" after "storeValues", not "createNewClass"

Comment: For starters, `storeValues` doesn't return a promise. Though it's not necessary in your example, since you're not running anything asyncrhonous.

Comment: Thank you. Promise is one of the tries I made to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a callback like this, **if** your `storeValues` is not synchronous like in your example:

```
$('.tableClassHeader').on('click', '.createClass', function(){
    storeValues(createNewClass);
});

function storeValues(callback){
    cl_year = $('.newClassForm').find('select[name=cl_year]').val();
    cl_course = $('.newClassForm').find('select[name=cl_course]').val();
    callback();
}

function createNewClass(){
    alert(cl_year);
}
```

If it is synchronous, just calling `createNewClass` after `storeValues` is enough.

What this does is:

- offers you the ability to pass a function of choice to the `storeValues`
- inside `storeValues` it calls the callback function passed as parameter

If you need to execute your function with a different scope you can use `call` or `apply`.

---

Another way to do this, without callbacks would be using

http://api.jquery.com/promise/
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/
http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/

Example as seen here http://jsfiddle.net/47fXF/1/ :

```
$('.tableClassHeader').on('click', '.createClass', function(){
    $.when(storeValues()).then(createNewClass);
});

function storeValues(){
    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('storing values');
        cl_year = $('.newClassForm').find('select[name=cl_year]').val();
        cl_course = $('.newClassForm').find('select[name=cl_course]').val();
        dfd.resolve();
    }, 1000);

    return dfd.promise();
}

function createNewClass(){
    alert("trololo");
}
```

Added the `setTimeout` to simulate asynchronicity.

If your `storeValues` is making only one ajax request using jQuery, then you can return it directly as shown in the API documentation.

Also make sure to call `resolve()`, `reject()` appropriately.

Comment: There is no need to use a callback for synchronous execution. This is an anti pattern.

Comment: @Johan from what I understood, `storeValues` is not synchronous. The name suggest an asynchronous operation and when it is done, it should call the next function.

Comment: Well, based on OP's post, it is. Also, there is no need for `call`/`apply` if you want to pass parameters. You could simply do `callback(whatever)`.

Comment: Updated the answer as per what you said @Johan

Answer (score 0):

Call like this . it first call the storeValues after executes the createNewClass function

```
$('.tableClassHeader').on('click', '.createClass', function(){

    storeValues(function() {
        createNewClass();
    });

});

function storeValues(callback){
    cl_year = $('.newClassForm').find('select[name=cl_year]').val();
    cl_course = $('.newClassForm').find('select[name=cl_course]').val();
    callback();
}
```

Comment: The value of the select element itself contains the correct value. Why would he need to target the selected option?

Comment: thank you, anyway .val() has always been right for me, it stores value attribute from the selected option

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I have tried calling the way you explain and it just makes nothing: alert does not display and no error is shown on fireBug...

Comment: UPDATE: your method executes storeValues, as a new added alert in there has shown, but it does not execute the second function

Comment: sorry i forgot to post the function stores values